# Java Reflection objetos aninhados

Tags: java, reflexão

Olá, boa tarde a todos.

Estou estudando java reflection e minha dúvida é se seria possível e como pegar Objetos aninhados **dinamicamente** como no exemplo logo abaixo:

```
public class Rg{
       Integer numRg;
}
public class Pessoa{ 
       String nome;
       Rg rg;
}
```

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, você pode acessar os atributos de uma classe através das funções [getDeclaredFields()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()) e [getType()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()), e ir repetindo até chegar onde deseja.

```
Class pessoaClass = Pessoa.class;
Field[] pessoaFields = pessoaClass.getDeclaredFields();

for (Field pessoaField : pessoaFields) {
    if (pessoaField.getName() == "rg") {
        Class rgClass = pessoaField.getType();
        Field[] rgFields = rgClass.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field rgField : rgFields) {
            System.out.println(rgField.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta Marlon!